# Submit Form on Cascading DropDown Change Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

i have a cascading dropwdown lists done in Jquery they work pretty well but i have a problem with submiting a form when the second dropDown change, here is my code.

```
$("#Bank").change(function () {
        var bankId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax("/App/BankBranch/ByBank", {
            data: { "id": bankId },
            type: "get", contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                var options = $("#id");
                options.html("");
                $.each(result, function () {

                    options.append($("<option />").val(this.Id).text(this.Name));

                });

            }

        });

    }).trigger('change'); //to make the event run on initialization for default value



        $('#id').change(function() {
            this.form.submit();

    });
```

the form only submits when i select a value from the dropdown but when the first dropwdown fills with data the second one, it does not submit the form.

**Update** 
Added HTML

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

            <h4>Seleccione Sucursal</h4>
            @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get))
                {
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        @Html.Label("Banco")
                        @{Html.RenderAction("GetAllBanks", "Bank", new { ControlName = "Bank" });}
                      &nbsp;
                   </div>

                <div class="pull-left">
                    @Html.Label("Sucursal")
                    @Html.DropDownList("id", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),null ,new {name="id", @class="input-medium"})
                 </div>
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#id').change(function() {
        this.form.submit();; //double semi-colon here, remove and it should be fine

 });
```

Comment: try giving the form an ID and call submit() on the form ID.

Comment: I try that too, and nothing im thinking the jquery change only triggers when i click the dropdown

Comment: Does that not mean it's working? I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to achieve. Upon changing #id dropdown the form doesn't submit? Maybe try using .bind() or .live() on the #id because you're changing the options with jQuery. So $('#id').bind('change',function(){ this.form.submit(); });